# Proof of linear independence of non-empty subsets

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question states:

> Show that if $S = \{v_1, v_2, \ldots , v_r\}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors, then so is every non-empty subset of $S$.

I understand that if $r>n$, $S$ is linearly dependent, but other than that, I'm not sure where to start with this proof.

Comment: Sorry about that... also, I don't understand how the sigma notation you are using here works. I've learned series in calculus, but I'm not sure what it means in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be using proof by contradiction as mentioned in one of the answers.
$$S=(v_1,v_2,........v_n)$$
Let $S_0$ be a subset of $S$ and assume that $S_0$ is linearly dependent 
$$S_0=(a_1,a_2,a_3.........,a_b)$$ where $b<n$. Since it is linearly dependent there exists scalars $(k_1,k_2,.......,k_b)$ such that $$a_1k_1+a_2k_2+.........+a_bk_b=0$$ but this can only happen when $b>n$ but in this case we had written that $b<n$. So therefore we arrive at a contradiction and our assumption is false.

Hence proved. Q.E.D

Answer (score 1):

Let $T\subseteq S$. Assume $\sum_{v\in T}c_vv=0$. By letting $c_v=0$ for $v\in S\setminus T$, we obtain $\sum _{v\in S}c_vv=0$, hence by linear independence $c_v=0$ for all $v\in S$ (and of course even more so for all $v\in T$).

In short: If it is not possible to find a non-trivial linear dependence among the vectors of $S$ when you are allowed to use them all, how could such a linear dependence suddenly be possible when you decide to voluntarily do without some of them?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, by contrary, that $ S_0$ be a dependent subset of $S$ and try to get a contradiction.